# Nagios max_check_attempts/retry interval ignored with host checks

Tags: nagios

I'm running Nagios 3.2.3 and I have a mysterious issue with host checks. Here's an example host definition.

```
define host {
  host_name HOST
  contacts CONTACTS_HERE
  alias ALIAS
  max_check_attempts 15
  check_interval 5
  active_checks_enabled 1
  passive_checks_enabled 1
  check_period 24x7
  obsess_over_host 0
  retry_interval 1
  check_freshness 0
  freshness_threshold 120
  retain_status_information 1
  retain_nonstatus_information 1
  low_flap_threshold 0
  high_flap_threshold 0
  flap_detection_enabled 0
  process_perf_data 1
  notification_interval 120
  notification_period 24x7
  notification_options d,u,r
  check_command check-host-alive
  icon_image_alt Linux
  icon_image linux40.png
  statusmap_image linux40.gd2
}
```

As you can see, max_check_attempts is set to 15 and retry_interval is set to 1 minute. The check command looks like this:

```
define command {
  command_name check-host-alive
  command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H $HOSTNAME$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 1
}
```

What happens however is this sequence of events:

```
Host Up[01-30-2017 21:41:56] HOST ALERT: HOST_NAME;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.17 ms
Host Down[01-30-2017 21:41:21] HOST ALERT: HOST_NAME;DOWN;HARD;1;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
Host Down[01-30-2017 21:41:10] HOST ALERT: HOST_NAME;DOWN;SOFT;1;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
```

So, after the first check failure, the host goes into a hard state instead of trying the check for 15 times 1 minute apart. I should add that this seems to happen when the host is not really down but extremely busy.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
  Sergei

Comment: What is your `interval_length` set to?

Comment: interval_length=60

Comment: Are you using a host template?  Is this host a member of a host group?

Comment: No using a template and it's not part of a host group.

Comment: If you have service checks defined, maybe the hosts checks are rescheduled because a change in one of the associated services state is detected as mentionned [here](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/issues/336) and in the [documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/hostchecks.html) (here for Nagios4 but it's the same for Nagios3)